# Cant embed google drive in the modal window through iframe

Tags: html, iframe

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />


<div class="modal fade" id="ModalDrive" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content event-date-modal">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: rgb(18, 20, 25);" id="event-date-cal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times" style="color: white;"></i>
                    </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title text-right" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color: white; font-weight: 600;">GOOGLE DRIVE
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe scrolling='yes' title='Parallax Mountains' src='https://drive.google.com/' frameborder='no' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='true' style='width: 100%; height: 30rem;'>
                    </iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-ftr">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<center>
  <button class="mt-5" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalDrive">
    Open Drive
  </button>
</center>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I want the user to manage the google drive: add files, delete files, and see content, in the google drive from a modal window. But Google Drive cant open in this iframe. Even the link like `https://www.google.com` doesn't open and the modal shows this error `www.google.com refused to connect.` I don't know how the iframe works. This is the first time I am using it. If the drive can be opened through an iframe, how to authenticate and store the credentials for a particular browser session, so the user doesn't have to login every time

Comment: I think you need to look into the Drive API to add the functionality you want. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/

Comment: Well, I can't find anything related to my use. From the information given in the docs it seems like I have to make a whole new modal window, which should look like drive and filter views of files and folders by fetching data through drive api. I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

For every google app you need an API. You can get it in the google drive docs.
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/get-started

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).